# python-telegram-bot CallbackQueryHandler doesn't work on the last message after restarting the bot

Tags: python, callback, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using `python-telegram-bot` to create a bot.

The bot waits for a message from the user after launch and does not work, when I click on the buttons of the message that the bot sent, it first needs to receive a message from the user

The buttons on the last message start working only when a user writes a message, that is, the past message will no longer make sense

```
def main() -> None: application = Application.builder().token(telegram_token).build()
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
                      MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, main_menu),
                      MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, main_menu)],
        states={
            START_ROUTES: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu_over, pattern="return_to_menu"),

                CallbackQueryHandler(support_menu, pattern="support"),
            ],
            END_ROUTES: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu_over, pattern="return_to_menu"),
            ],
        },
        fallbacks=[
                   MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, main_menu),
                   MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, main_menu)],
    )
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)`
```

I thought there was some way to receive a callback query from a user after launching the bot, and not a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what way to interpret your question, so I'm providing answers to possible interpretations:

- The entry points to your conversation handler are `MessageHandler` s. If you want the conversation to be started via a button, use a `CallbackQueryHandler` (in addition or instead)
- The current state of a conversation is not saved across restarts of the python script by default. If you want that, please have a look at [PTBs built-in persistence setup](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.